# Dialog won't appear in android, why?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

This is my dialog java file that's making the trouble. It's very alike other dialog files I have which work just fine. The thing is that this dialog is called when another progress dialog is finished. The other one closes but this new one won't open (but the code runs) and I don't understand why.

```
public class Response extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {

    Button cpandclose;
    EditText response;
    Context context;

    //Skapar dialog med About xml filen
    public Response(Context context, String url) {
        super(context);
        /** 'Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE' - Used to hide the title */
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        /** Design the dialog in main.xml file */
        setContentView(R.layout.response);

        cpandclose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cpandclose);
        cpandclose.setOnClickListener(this);
        response = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.resposeurl);
        response.setText("http://xxx.com/i/" + url);
        this.context = context;
        Log.d("Response Window: ", "running..");
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == cpandclose) {
            ClipboardManager ClipMan = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipMan.setText(response.getText());
            dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

The `xml-file` for the dialog that won't show:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/responsetxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Response:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/resposeurl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cpandclose"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Copy and Close" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The app function by uploading some data in the background and when it's finished it apply the data returned to a string:

```
camera.responseFromServer(serverResponse);
```

That calls the method responseFromServer in the current camera object and the function that it's calling is the following:

```
public void responseFromServer(String url) {
Looper.prepare();
Response response = new Response(this, url);
Log.d("response: ", url);
response.show();
}
```

This runs the program, but I can't see any dialog showing up. How can that be? It might be an easy solution but it feels like I've tried everything!

Thanks for your advice and better wisdom.

Answer (score 3):

Because the dialog should not be created in `responseFromServer()` but in `onCreateDialog()`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you unaccept this answer? Best regards.

Comment: Because it didn't work. I followed the guidelines from the android dev site and the dialog won't show when I've received data from my server.  I can post more details when I am home if you want to look into it. :)

Comment: For clearance: It works, but as soon as I receive post-data from my server it acts like this example.